# Tracking direct file downloads with Google Analytics and Varnish proxy

Tags: google-analytics, drupal-7, varnish

I am using Google Analytics and I want to track direct file downloads (when someone hits myserver.com/file.pdf directly). Obviously Google Analytics won't track this if it's set up with client-side javascript.

I am also using Varnish proxy which means my server doesn't necessarily even see the request if Varnish responds with a cached copy of file.pdf - so I assume that giving GA my server logs won't work nor will custom PHP on my server that runs on every file request.

What is the best way of incorporating file downloads into Google Analytics in this case?

Answer (score 0):

only option i could foresee it use the varnishncsa log file to track the requests to these files, and then using the GA measurement protocol pass them over to GA. That would be a viable route to go.